# MVC4 - post string always null

Tags: c#, json, post

I am using post method (MCV4 - Web API - apicontroller), like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, value);
}
```

I am using google chrome - advanced rest client add-in.

1. For some reason the value is always null (I passed it on raw - payload part of advanced rest client).
2. I need to change always the content type to json/application (manually in google chrome advanced rest client) - Can I force some defaults (on webapiconfig.cs or elsewhere)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you've already found a solution, but I've been fighting with this the last half hour and came across your question (without a solution), and since I finally got it to work, I figured I'd post my solution:

Leave the Content-Type as:

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

In the Raw Payload, enter the string you want to pass in as:

```
=mystring
```

Note the equal sign before your string with nothing before it.